# Crystal Report - Group Expert Issue (Specified Order)

Tags: sorting, crystal-reports

I'm pulling statistics from a database for a lab. I am using Group Expert, specified order, to organize the positioning of records in my report and the function is not working for 1 group and I have no idea why.

This is an example of what my report looks like now.

[image: Image1]

I initially added `Influenza SARS-COV-2 Multiplex rRT-PCR` to my group expert and it worked as it should, it moved that record to the top of that group.  However, when I added `HIV-1/HIV-2 CMIA` to the group expert list, it remained in the same position.  I tried adding a different item to that list `(Coronavirus 229E HKU1 NL63 OC43)` and it worked just fine.

[image][image]

I tried adding other items to the list and they also worked. What is preventing this 1 record from following the sorting criteria?

Answer (score 0):

The value you added seems wrong.
Instead of ***HIV-1/HIV-2 CMIA*** it should probably be ***HIV1/HIV2 CMIA***

Comment: Not an option.  I'm adding the group expert sorting on my Group4 which are the names listed in the 2nd column in the pictures above. HIV1/HIV2 CMIA is not in the 2nd column.  The names that worked when put into the specified order are all names in the 2nd column.

Comment: Just for kicks I manually typed HIV1/HIV2 CMIA and nothing.